# Handling Lucene query parser errors

Tags: lucene.net

My application takes a user inputted string and tries to parse it with the Lucene query parser. I noticed however that there are several formats of strings that provoke an error in this query parser.
e.g.:

- ~anystring
- anystring +

First I tried molding my user inputted string so that it could not contain these cases, but as I see it, there could be more cases I do not foresee now.

How do you handle Query parser exceptions? How do you prevent them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We catch the remaining parse exceptions and display an error message ("Your search did not match any documents. Suggestion: Try different keywords.").

See also [How to make the Lucene QueryParser more forgiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263081/how-to-make-the-lucene-queryparser-more-forgiving)

Comment: Hmm, yes, this is the most obvious way to go. But I would think that some common cases would be solved by the query parser itselve. But maybe that shouldn't be it's resposibility indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.replace(/([\!\*\+\&\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\^\~\?\:\"\/])/g, "");
```

Comment: Can you provide more information / context in your answer?