# Umbraco Lucene search breaking on 'special characters'

Tags: lucene, umbraco, lucene.net, umbraco7

When a user inputs certain special characters i.e a html tag, the user receives this:

*Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/ezSearch.cshtml)*

I have been investigating and this seems to be a common issue and I attempted to apply a fix so it would strip out 'bad' characters:

```
public string CleanseSearchTerm(string input)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
    input = rgx.Replace(input, "");

    return input.ToString();
}
```

However, the issue is that this error is getting generated before it has a chance to hit my method to strip out 'bad' characters. Any ideas of how this can be resolved?

Comment: Is examine  returning the error or is a global configuration that triggers the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected "  message?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried these changes myself Kyle but I have done some investigation to help you fix this problem. Could one of the following solutions help you?

See [this Umbraco form question](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/website-utilities/ezsearch/bugs-feedback-suggestions/59447-Special-Characters-in-Search-Term) and its answers, especially the one from [Ismail Mayat](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/website-utilities/ezsearch/bugs-feedback-suggestions/59447-Special-Characters-in-Search-Term#comment-215504) could help you.

Linked to Ismail's answer, there is also this ["How to make the Lucene QueryParser more forgiving?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263081/how-to-make-the-lucene-queryparser-more-forgiving) question and I'd recommend you to check the answers for this question, too.

Another answer that might help you is [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654466/1587012)

Answer (score 0):

Lucene.NET does contain a few classes to help with HTML stripping.  These classes are located [here](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/tree/master/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/CharFilter) in the Lucene.NET repo. Specifically, the [HTMLStripCharFilter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/lucenenet/master/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/CharFilter/HTMLStripCharFilter.cs) may be of interest.